# Was Armageddon always Ullanor in Canon?

Tags: warhammer-40k

In the Beast Arises series the Beast is found to be based on Ullanor.

Once the Ork threat has been neutralised the Mechanicum "destroy" the planet. However what they actually do is use the Orks own tech to transport it to a new system, strip it of all its interesting tech and then rename it Armageddon.

it then becomes the focus of numerous attacks by Chaos and Ork armies and gives rise to Yarrick.

Is this history of Armageddon new to the novel series, or have Games Workshop hinted at, or stated it in the past prior to the release of the books?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asked Guy Haley on Twitter:

[image: Tweet]

Tweet can be found [here](https://twitter.com/SornDuskryn/status/1230812445943508992?s=20)

His answer:

> The connection between Armageddon and Ullanor wasn't there when the planet was invented. Like a lot of WH40K lore, it just developed. Most of this stuff isn't planned out in such detail years in advance (10+ in this case), but we try to make it look that way!
>
> [This is his tweet](https://twitter.com/GuyHaley/status/1230827126842064897?s=20)

---

My previous answer from before *Guy Haleys* tweet:

Armageddon is part of WH40k since at least 1992 with the board game *Battle for Armageddon*:

> Das Spiel Battle for Armageddon ist ein Brettspiel im Warhammer 40.000-Universum.
>
> - Erscheinungsjahr: 1992
>
> From the German Lexicanum on [Battle for Armageddon](https://wh40k-de.lexicanum.com/wiki/Battle_for_Armageddon_(Spiel))

Translation:

> The game *Battle for Armageddon* is a board game in the Warhammer 40.000-universe.
>
> - Published: 1992

First mention of Ullanor I could find was in *Index Astartes IV* from 2004. I don't own the book so I use the quote from the Lexicanum Article on [Horus Lupercal](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Horus_Lupercal):

> As the Emperor and the Great Crusade marched on, Horus proved himself to be a tactical genius. He knew precisely which force to send and where to send it, showing no mercy to those that opposed the Emperor but sparing the innocent from unnecessary bloodshed. As the Emperor departed to find and meet with rediscovered Primarchs, Horus was left in temporary command of the Legiones Astartes and this helped prepare him for the role of Warmaster.
>
> They cite [*Index Astartes IV*](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Index_Astartes#Index_Astartes_IV)

The transportation of *Ullanor* into *Segmentum Solar* was described in *The Beast Arises: The Beheading*, published in November 2016. I don't think they've planned this 12 or more years ahead.

Comment: The english version of the first mention for Battle for Armageddon can be foun on White Dwarf (UK) 151, of the same year of your source (1992). https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/White_Dwarf_151_(UK)

Comment: @RichardC Updated my answer with Guy Haleys tweet, so you have a definitve answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can't recall any hint or statement in any book or codex or any canon pubblication prior to the Beast Arises series, I also made some digging to see if there was some "missed hint" without any luck.

So: **No, the fact that Ullanor and Armageddon are the same Planet it's something new introduced with the Beast Arises series.**

The only thing they had in common before this series is that they are both a common battleground between the Imperium of Man and the Orks.